# Chance a call will terminate in less than X minutes

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question regarding probability.

If I have Y number of calls, say 100, and they have a random duration in which one call can have a duration of 5 second, a other call can have a duration of 500 seconds, what is the probability that a call will terminate in less than X seconds, say 60.

For example, my inputs are:

- Number of calls: 100 calls
- Minimum call length: 1 second
- Maximum call length: 500 seconds
- Total duration of calls: 409 minutes or 24540 seconds

In the case above, what is the probability that a call will terminate in less than 1 minute?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any sense for how the lengths are distributed?  Do you know the mean call length?  The standard deviation?

Comment: Mean call length is 245.4 seconds. 
Standard deviation is146.8338231.

Lengths between calls you mean? In this case, irrelevant.

Comment: You could do a few things to analyze this.  You could view this as being approximately exponentially distributed since you are trying to determine the probability of the phone call by a certain time, in which case you'd be looking at something like $$ P(\text{call lasts less than 1 minute}) = \int_1^{60} \lambda e^{-\lambda (t-1)} \, dt$$ where $\lambda = 1/\mu = 1/245.4$

Comment: Ah thank you. I think I dealt with integrals last time few years ago, so just to confirm:

t = number of calls in a give time, 100, correct? 

When I type this into my calculator, I get 0.1571 (15.71% of calls terminating <1 minute), correct?

I was thinking of using Poisson distibution.

Comment: In my notation $t$ would be the duration of a single call and the exponential distribution (which is usually used to model "time until event occurs" types of questions) would give us the probability of the end of the call occurring before 60 seconds have elapsed via the integral I wrote above.  Writing it slightly differently, you could say $t=$duration of a phone call in seconds and the integral above is equal to $P(1\leq t\leq 60)$, the probability that the call ends before 1 minute.

Comment: I am sorry for being a bit slow. :) okay, but which single call, any in the 1≤t≤60 range?

Comment: If I understand your original question correctly, you are given 100 data points (the 100 original call durations) and you are then asked to make a prediction about any phone call lasting less than 1 minute.  In this case, I would approach it in a manner like I described above, where you use the data from 100 calls to try and predict how long another call would last.

Comment: It's like saying that you know from some data that has been collected that the average time it takes an ambulance to reach someone after calling for help is 16 minutes, so what is the probability that it reaches the next caller in under 10 minutes (I made these numbers up, of course)